How do I set up a reCAPTCHA key using the Essentials tier instead of Enterprise?
I've been trying to set up a basic reCAPTCHA key (using the Essentials or Standard tier), but everywhere I go in the Google reCAPTCHA console seems to push me towards using reCAPTCHA Enterprise. I don't need the Enterprise features and want to use the free tier that was previously available for reCAPTCHA v2 or v3.
Has Google changed how to access the standard reCAPTCHA, or am I missing something? Can someone guide me on how to generate a site key for reCAPTCHA Essentials (Standard reCAPTCHA)?
Thanks in advance for any help!

The term "Enterprise" in this case is overloaded and refers to:

reCAPTCHA Enterprise API


One of the billing tiers

Reposting this answer from the Google Cloud Community

All three reCAPTCHA tiers (Essentials, Standard and Enterprise) run on the reCAPTCHA Enterprise API. We know it’s a bit confusing to have to enable an “enterprise” API if you’re just looking for the most basic setup, but the advantage is it makes it a lot easier to seamlessly upgrade when needed.
All you need to do is to enable the API and create a key and the system will automatically assign you to the most appropriate tier. Below is the basic logic:

If you create a new account without billing enabled you will be put in the Essentials tier. That gives you 10K assessments per month on a basic set of features.
If your account has billing enabled congratulations you are in the Standard tier. This gives you access to advanced features, and don’t worry you still get 10K free assessments.
When you hit 10K+1 assessments each month in the Standard tier you will be charged a flat $8 that covers your usage up to 100K assessments.
At 100K+1 assessments each month you automatically transition to the Enterprise tier where you will be charged $0.001 per assessment over 100K.
For high volume users, contact Sales to discuss a subscription with volume discounts.

Hope that helps. Thank you for being a reCAPTCHA customer!

So you still create and configure your reCAPTCHA key through the Google Cloud Console as usual
https://console.cloud.google.com/security/recaptcha
Then depending if you have billing enabled and your current API usage for the month that will determine which billing tier you automatically fall into.
